# Pipe PhantomJS output to FFmpeg

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, ffmpeg, phantomjs

I am running PhantomJS using Selenium WebDriver (C#).

I'm trying to video record my browser using FFmpeg as shown in the 2 tutorials:

> https://mindthecode.com/recording-a-website-with-phantomjs-and-ffmpeg/
>
> https://gist.github.com/phanan/e03f75082e6eb114a35c

As explained in the tutorials, I'll need to pipe output the phantomJS process to ffmpeg.

I know how to add arguments to phantomjs, like the following:

```
    var svz = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
    svz.AddArgument("ffmpeg -y -c:v png -f image2pipe -r 24 -t 10  -i - -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart output.mp4");
    var driver = new PhantomJSDriver(svz);
```

However, I don't know how to add the argument as pipe. I have tried adding the pipe symbol before the actual argument but that doesn't seem to work.

So, my question is, how do I pipe the output of PhantomJS using selenium webdriver?

Comment: You would need a series of images (frames) written to STDOUT so you could pipe them to FFMPEG.  Selenium webdriver can't do that.  what you are asking is not possible.